# C# Graphics Rectangle Rotating Violently

Tags: c#, visual-studio, graphics, youtube

As a bit of background I have been using C# for quite a while just not in this type of use case. My tutor as a little challenge asked me to "Rotate a rectangle".
I achieved this by using Graphics and the Matrix.RotateAt method.
It all worked fine with a single rectangle. However I wanted to expand upon it and create a class called "Square" which has a position and size and a function to rotate it.
Currently I have modified this idea a bit and now am having an issue where the Square seems to rotate violently.

I created a very short video and uploaded it to YouTube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KwQjDKfExtg&feature=youtu.be

Here you can see I tried to comment out all unnecessary code.

```
//Import this namespace which it auto-generated for my Square class.
using CSharpIntro.Classes.Shapes_Rotation;

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CSharpIntro
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //int rotateDegrees = 0;
    int numOfSquares = 1;
    List<Square> squares = new List<Square>();

    //Instantiate a new Matrix class.
    Matrix myMatrix = new Matrix();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfSquares; i++)
        {
            Square square = new Square();
            //Random rand = new Random();
            //square.boxX = rand.Next(0, ActiveForm.Size.Width);
            //square.boxY = rand.Next(0, ActiveForm.Size.Height);
            squares.Add(square);
            //MessageBox.Show("A square has been created");
        }
    }

    //private void DrawLineOnScreen()
    //{
    //  Random rand = new Random();

    //  Color randomColour = new Color();
    //  randomColour = Color.FromArgb(rand.Next(0, 255), rand.Next(0, 255), rand.Next(0, 255));

    //  Pen myPen = new Pen(randomColour);
    //  Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics();

    //  graphics.DrawLine(myPen, rand.Next(0, ActiveForm.Size.Width), rand.Next(0, ActiveForm.Size.Height), rand.Next(0, ActiveForm.Size.Width), rand.Next(0, ActiveForm.Size.Height));

    //  myPen.Dispose();
    //  graphics.Dispose();
    //}

    private void RectRotateTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    //  Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);
    //  Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics();
    //  graphics.Clear(Color.White);

    //  int boxX = 100;
    //  int boxY = 100;

    //  int boxWidth = 100;
    //  int boxHeight = 100;

    //  //Get the rotation point
    //  //get the X position of the rectangle and add half of thw width to get the X.
    //  //get the Y position of the rectangle and add half of the height to get the Y.
    //  PointF rotatePoint = new PointF((boxX + (boxWidth / 2)), (boxY + (boxHeight / 2)));
    //  myMatrix.RotateAt(rotateDegrees, rotatePoint, MatrixOrder.Append);

    //  graphics.Transform = myMatrix;
    //  graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, boxX, boxY, boxWidth, boxHeight);

    //  //Increment the rotation by 1 each tick.
    //  rotateDegrees += 1;

    //  //If rotateDegress is greater than 360, set it to 0.
    //  //360 is a full spin.
    //  if (rotateDegrees > 360)
    //      rotateDegrees = 0;

    //  //Debug information.
    //  //Console.WriteLine(rotateDegrees);

    //  //Dispose of the graphics and pen so we dont cause a memory leak.
    //  myPen.Dispose();
    //  graphics.Dispose();
    }

    private void RotateAllSquares_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DrawAllRectangles();
    }

    public void DrawAllRectangles()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < squares.Count; i++)
        {
            Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
            Graphics graphics = CreateGraphics();
            graphics.Clear(Color.White);

            PointF rotatePoint = new PointF((squares[i].boxX + (squares[i].boxWidth / 2)), (squares[i].boxY + (squares[i].boxHeight / 2)));
            myMatrix.RotateAt(squares[i].rotateDegrees, rotatePoint, MatrixOrder.Append);
            graphics.Transform = myMatrix;

            graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, squares[i].boxX, squares[i].boxY, squares[i].boxWidth, squares[i].boxHeight);

            squares[i].rotateDegrees ++;

            myPen.Dispose();
            graphics.Dispose();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("A square has been rotated at {0}, {1}", squares[i].boxX, squares[i].boxY));
            Console.WriteLine(squares[i].rotateDegrees);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And here is the simple Square class which as you can see is also mostly commented out now.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;

namespace CSharpIntro.Classes.Shapes_Rotation
{
public class Square
{
    //Create the variables with some basic numbers
    //Just in case they dont get set for some reason.
    public int boxX = 100;
    public int boxY = 100;
    public int boxWidth = 100;
    public int boxHeight = 100;

    public int rotateDegrees = 0;

    //Create a new Matrix class
    Matrix myMatrix = new Matrix();

    public void IncrementRotationDegrees()
    {
        rotateDegrees += 1;
        if (rotateDegrees > 360)
            rotateDegrees = 1;
    }

    //public void RotateSquare()
    //{
    //  Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 5);

    //  //Instantiate a new Form1 just so I can access CreateGraphics().
    //  Form1 form = new Form1();
    //  Graphics graphics = form.CreateGraphics();

    //  graphics.Clear(Color.White);

    //  //Get the rotation point
    //  //get the X position of the rectangle and add half of thw width to get the X.
    //  //get the Y position of the rectangle and add half of the height to get the Y.
    //  PointF rotatePoint = new PointF((boxX + (boxWidth / 2)), (boxY + (boxHeight / 2)));
    //  myMatrix.RotateAt(rotateDegrees, rotatePoint, MatrixOrder.Append);

    //  graphics.Transform = myMatrix;
    //  graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, boxX, boxY, boxWidth, boxHeight);

    //  //Increment the rotation by 1 each tick.
    //  rotateDegrees += 1;

    //  //If rotateDegress is greater than 360, set it to 0.
    //  //360 is a full spin.
    //  if (rotateDegrees > 360)
    //      rotateDegrees = 0;

    //  //Debug information.
    //  //Console.WriteLine(rotateDegrees);

    //  //Dispose of the graphics and pen so we dont cause a memory leak.
    //  myPen.Dispose();
    //  graphics.Dispose();
    //}
}
}
```

As most of this code has been commented out I still just have no idea what could be causing it to spin violently.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the properties of RotateAllSquares that you place on your Form?

Comment: Enabled of course with a 10ms interval. Meaning it should take 3.6 seconds to do a full rotation. I will get a video of it working normally with the old method if I can.

Comment: Looks like you keep adding to the rotation angle but never reset the matrix. The rotation therefore grows and grows.. If you want it uniform don't change it from, say, 1, or simply reset the matrix...

Comment: Thanks! I had to reset the matrix. First time using a matrix within real programming so thanks so much for that. Sure as hell wont be making that mistake again now I know you must reset it.

Answer (score 0):

So that this post is answered, you must reset your Matrix using:

myMatrix.Reset();

or whatever your matrix is called.

Thanks for the help in the comments.